# how do i change my shortcuts for zoom, move the view, and rotate?

Tags: shortcut

my old shortcut for zoom was ctrl, alt and mouse, left (this is on laptop) however when i try to do this it wont let me drag the zoom,

second my old rotate was alt and mouse, left.

and last my move view was shift alt mouse.

(all mouse buttons you click and drag).

I can't change these and if i try, for example i tried o fix my zoom. I couldn't drag I could only click. I need help with this

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help you
[image]
[image]
go to 3d view
[image]
And now you have to do the same thing for the 2d view etc and the rotation